# Rails: belongs_to & accepts_nested_attributes_for, polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on my first Rails project, and I have the following model relationship:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :identifiable, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :students

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, as: :identifiable
  attr_accessible :profile
```

The associated controllers are:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    if @student.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
   end
  end
end
```

And

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

 def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
    @profile.save
 end
end
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new `Student` with the following form, which is in `students\new.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Create a new Student Account</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
  <%= form_for(@student) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <%= f.fields_for :profile, @profile do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.label :name %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name %>

      <%= builder.label :email %>
      <%= builder.text_field :email %>

      <%= builder.label :password %>
      <%= builder.password_field :password %>

      <%= builder.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= builder.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></p>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting the following error message when I try to submit the form: `No association found for name 'students'. Has it been defined yet?` What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for a model to accept nested attributes for another model, the association to the other model needs to be declared. In `Profile` you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :students`, but there is no corresponding association defined (e.g. `has_many :students`), which is why you're getting that particular error. In your case, this association wouldn't be correct, however.

Usually, if model `A` accepts nested attributes for model `B`, either `A` `has_many` `B` or `A` `has_one` `B`. In your case, you have `A` `belongs_to` `B`. A better design would be

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :identifiable, polymorphic: true

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :profile_attributes
  has_one :profile, as: :identifiable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

Comment: Is there a way to do same with Profile form instead of Student?

Answer (score 1):

Should your student be singular? ie: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :student`

Edit: Also, your Student should accept nested attributes for a Profile, if the Student has_one profile, and the Student form contains the fields_for call (I think...)